# Как сделать контейнер по ширине содержимого?

Tags: html, css, css3

Как сделать .inside по ширине содержимого и выровнять его по центру над элементом .container?

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: -10px;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #858585;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.inside {
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  left: -10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid #858585;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inside">1000000</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приблизительно так

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 20px;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #858585;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.inside {
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #858585;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inside">1000000</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а почему left: -50%; и width: 20px; в элемент::before ? как это нагуглить?

Comment: это центрирование, margin = -( ширина / 2). Еще как вариант вместо margin использовать transform: translateX(-50%)

Comment: это я знаю. мне не понятно почему эти стили применяются к container::before а не к container

Comment: а почему эти стили должны применяться к container?

Comment: я этого не утверждаю, а хочу разобраться. не понятно, например, почему width: 20px применяется к container::before. ::before это же не сам элемент, а псевдо элемент до него

Comment: потому что  используется position: absolute;

Answer (score 1):

Простой вариант для частного случая, когда .inside — что-то вроде счетчика над кнопкой:

```css
.block {
  margin: 50px;
}

.container {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #858585;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.inside {
  border: 1px solid #858585;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -30px);
  width:fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inside">1000000</div>
  </div>
</div>
```